# How to animate a image from a collection view cell to move to full screen by tapping on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, fullscreen

I have a horizontal scroll single section collection view of images

When you tap on first image in the `collectionview`, the image should "grow" with a smooth transition to take up the full screen while the screen behind fades to full black.  Tapping the image or the "x" in the top right corner fades this screen out and returns you to your previous screen.

I can get the image from this method

`-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

How can this kind of animation be achieved?

Following is the sample image,

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

     //if u want to move it to center before you make it big use all code       
     imgView.center = self.view.center;        

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{

        //just use this if you want it to move to full screen            
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);            
    }];      
}];
```

Hope this helps !